# Issues starting Kube-scheduler [ Kubernetes the hard way ]

Tags: linux, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to setup kubernetes cluster the hardway by following guide from Kelsey Hightower's [Kubernetes The Hard Way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/08-bootstrapping-kubernetes-controllers.md)

After setting up the `kube-scheduler`, when I start the scheduler I am seeing the following error:

```
Jan 20 10:20:01 xyz.com kube-scheduler[12566]: F0120 10:20:01.025675 12566 helpers.go:119] **error: no kind "KubeSchedulerConfiguration" is registered for version** "kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1beta1"
Jan 20 10:20:01 xyz.com kube-scheduler systemd1: kube-scheduler.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jan 20 10:20:01 xyz.com kube-scheduler systemd1: kube-scheduler.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 20 10:20:01 xyz.com kube-scheduler systemd1: kube-scheduler.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 20 10:20:06 xyz.com kube-scheduler systemd1: kube-scheduler.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
```

Can somebody please provide some pointers to what is going on or what am I missing? My `kube-apiserver` and `kube-controller-manager` are active.

My `kube-scheduler.yaml` inside `/etc/kubernetes/config` looks like this.

```
apiVersion: kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeSchedulerConfiguration
clientConnection:
  kubeconfig: "/var/lib/kubernetes/kube-scheduler.kubeconfig"
leaderElection:
  leaderElect: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `apiVersion` to `kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1beta2` or `kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1beta3`.
`v1beta1` is not supported in Kubernetes *1.21*.

You can see more [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kube-scheduler-config.v1beta2/#kubescheduler-config-k8s-io-v1beta2-KubeSchedulerConfiguration) (for *v1beta2*), and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kube-scheduler-config.v1beta3/#kubescheduler-config-k8s-io-v1beta3-KubeSchedulerConfiguration) (for *v1beta3*)

---

There is an issue opened in kubernetes-the-hard-way repo ([#687](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/issues/687)), that suggest changing apiVersion to `kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1`

Comment: Thanx for replying. I was able to sort it out yesterday by installing the newer version of the binaries and changing the API version in the kube scheduler file.